# How can i write, "if not greater than or equal to some value" eloquently?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, operators

I am reading, *Programming: Principle and Practice Using C++*, and Bjarne suggest avoiding overuse of parentheses. Is there an eloquent way to structure the following if statement? Here is my code:

```
bool is_valid(string s)
{ 
      if(!(s.size()>=8)) throw invalid_argument("Username must be 8 char or more");
      return true;
}
```

Comment: s.size() < 8  ...............

Comment: lol that makes sense @MitchWheat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of the function is bad. It always returns `true` and it is not clear why it throws an exception.

I should look like

```
bool is_valid( const string &s )
{
    return s.size() >= 8;
}
```

or

```
bool is_valid( const string &s )
{
    const std::string::size_type acceptable_size = 8;
    return s.size() >= acceptable_size;
}
```

Comment: that actually looks way better never thought about doing that way, which is why I came here for guidance, but in the book I am reading it says you should handle invalid input within the function, if you can. How would you suggest I handle the invalid length?

Comment: @Kevlwig Invalid input should be checked in another function that can call this function. As for your second comment then I have not understood it. What did you want to ask?

Comment: what does line 3 say?

Comment: @Kevlwig It is equivalent to the return statement in the previous implementation. Only a named constant for magic number 8 was introduced. The return statement returns true if the size of the string is greater than or equal to 8 and false otherwise.

Comment: I understand the defining of the named constant but I'm lost on the std::string::size_type.

Comment: @Kevlwig It is a typedef for an unsigned integer type defined in the class std::string that is used for example as the return type by the member function size().

Comment: makes sense now thank you.